# How can deploy JSON API of databricks scheduled JOB through azure devops cicd pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks

I have JSON API of my one of schedule notebook JOB

```
{
  "name": "itatesttable",
  "email_notifications": {
    "no_alert_for_skipped_runs": true
  },
  "webhook_notifications": {},
  "timeout_seconds": 0,
  "schedule": {
    "quartz_cron_expression": "36 0 13 * * ?",
    "timezone_id": "Asia/Calcutta",
    "pause_status": "UNPAUSED"
  },
  "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "task_key": "itatesttable",
      "run_if": "ALL_SUCCESS",
      "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": "/Users/pal.mor@bk.com/itatesttable",
        "source": "WORKSPACE"
      },
      "new_cluster": {
        "spark_version": "13.3.x-scala2.12",
        "azure_attributes": {
          "first_on_demand": 1,
          "availability": "ON_DEMAND_AZURE",
          "spot_bid_max_price": -1
        },
        "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
        "spark_env_vars": {
          "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
        },
        "enable_elastic_disk": true,
        "data_security_mode": "SINGLE_USER",
        "runtime_engine": "PHOTON",
        "num_workers": 8
      },
      "timeout_seconds": 0,
      "email_notifications": {}
    }
  ],
  "run_as": {
    "user_name": "pal.mor@bk.com"
  }
}
```

Through Azure devops cicd I want to deploy this on different environment or the workspace.

I want to automate scheduled job in azure databricks.